# TestNG : How to return List<String> from DataProvider method

Tags: java, testng

I am quite new to TestNG.

Following is my test method

```
@Test(dataProvider="getHRServiceData")
public void executeHRService(List<String> inputValues)
{
    //some code here
}
```

As you can see this method requires List inputValues as argument.

Following is my code for getHRServiceData() method

```
public Object[][] getHRServiceData() throws Exception 
{
    List<String> inputValues=Utils.getInputDataFromExcelFileAsList("HR");
    Object[][] objArray  = new Object[inputValues.length][]; 
    //Code to convert List<String> to Object[][]
}
```

In this method I get inputValues values in the form of List

But as return type is Object[][] I need to convert List into Object[][]

I am not sure how to convert List into Object[][]

Could you please help me here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TestNG. Your problem is to convert a `List<String>` to `Object[][]`. How to you see the result of converting a  1D list  into a 2D array? Do you intend to sspli each String into its individual characters? Or set dimension 2 to be size 1? You need to state/think clearer what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
@DataProvider (name = "getHRServiceData")
public Object[][] getHRServiceData() {
    return new Object[][] {
            {
                   Utils.getInputDataFromExcelFileAsList("HR");
            },
    };
}
```

Comment: Be careful, OP. I *believe* this creates a 2D array of size 1x1, with its only inner element being the original `List<String>`. The final Object is therefore actually a `List<String>[][]`. This certainly compiles, but does it really do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Sylvain, you may be right. But in my case I know there will be always single arraylist<String>. So for me this works.